# Where can I buy dried coffee cherries in the USA?

Tags: coffee-berries

I am looking for dried coffee cherries on behalf of my brother. He probably wants to encourage a market for them in order to reduce food waste. I'd support that too. Where can you find dried coffee cherries for purchase? I'd be ok buying them in any quantity, including bulk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nossa Familia Coffee](https://www.nossacoffee.com/products/cascara), a company based out of Portland OR, sells *Cascara* (i.e. Dried Coffee Husks) from Guatemala.

Hope this is helpful

Comment: You're my hero!!! I just bought some! Thank you so much! I was also told by some vendors in California to contact local coffee roasters in my area (I live in northeast Tennessee) and ask if they or their bean sources have any cascara to provide. I haven't done that yet but I will. Also, as a side note, I wasn't sure if cascara referred to just the skins, or if it included the meat of the fruit also. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Madcap, which currently has Costa Rican Cascara: https://madcapcoffee.com/shop/coffee/cascara/. I've bought it before and enjoyed it.

Answer (score 0):

What's the Buzz Coffee Co, out of College Station Tx sells cascara retail and wholesale.